# test method issue with soql that has "Where clause"

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I have the following code on one of my controller which I was trying to create a test class.

This is what my method looks like..

```
public static void RunMethod1() {
    try {
        List<Project__c> projectList = [SELECT Name, Client_Id__c FROM Project__c WHERE StageName = 'Booked'];
        if (!projectList.isEmpty())
        {
            //Does not go here
        }
        ...
    } catch (Exception e){
        ...
    }
}
```

and this my test class looks like.

```
Account testAcc = new Account(
    Name = 'test account'
);
insert testAcc;
system.assertNotEqual(testAcc.Id, null);

Project__c testProj = new Project__c (
    Name = 'test project',
    StageName = 'Booked',
    Client_Id__c = testAcc.Id
);
insert testProj;
system.assertNotEqual(testProj.Id, null);
system.assertEqual(testProj.StageName, 'Booked');

test.startTest();
    myController.RunMethod1();
test.stopTest();
```

The issue is why does the test method found `projectList` as an empty list? even if I have inserted the correct project. I even asserted its field `StageName` that is being used on the `WHERE clause`.

I tried to remove the `WHERE clause` from my method then it does go inside the if condition which is what I am also expecting to be covered as well even if I have a `WHERE clause` on my `SOQL`.

Any explanation? or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `StageName` is this a standard field in your `Project__c` object?

Comment: @highfive yes I just tried to contrived a code as an example . but in my account they were not really named like that :)

Comment: Suggest you post your actual code or review it against what you posted here as what you posted appears fine.

Comment: @Eric The code really looks like that , I just rename them :) . Yeah I am also certain that my code is fine .. That is why I am really wondering why does the test does not covers the code inside the if condition when I have the WHERE clause

Comment: Ok how about you query for the testproj after you insert it and assert the value of stagename then. Maybe it was changed from what you set it by code or wfr after insert. That's the next logical step in debugging short of full debug log review

Comment: @Eric *Maybe it was changed from what you set it by code or wfr after insert.* you are correct mate. The field `StageName` is being updated by one of our trigger so from `Booked` the Stage of the project that I inserted now has `Completed` stage so there is no really way my `projectList` can have a values with the `WHERE clause` searching for `Booked` projects. Thank you!

Comment: @JF-Mechs ok. Added it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your field is being changed after you insert it.

query for the testproj after you insert it and assert the value of stagename then. Maybe it was changed from what you set it by code or wfr after insert.

That's the next logical step in debugging short of full debug log review